# FastReport.Net. Export to xls

Tags: c#, fastreport

Below is the code that exports report to xml:

```
using (FastReport.Export.Xml.XMLExport export = new FastReport.Export.Xml.XMLExport())
{
    if (export.ShowDialog())
        export.Export(report1, @"result.xml");
}
```

but how to export report to xls-file?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the product you are using?

Comment: yes of course. have you?

Comment: I think what @DarrenYoung is saying is that you should clarify your question by sharing what you've tried and what you've found from the documentation concerning your problem. You can improve your question by making an [edit] to show your research effort.

Comment: @GrApDev Excel's format is the XML based `xlsx`, since 2007. You don't need to support `xls` unless you *really* need to support clients using Excel 2003

Answer (score 1):

I don't think FastReport.Net can export to .xls file. But it can export to .xlsx files. Try the following code:

```
using (var export = new FastReport.Export.OoXML.Excel2007Export())
{
    if (export.ShowDialog())
        export.Export(report1, @"result.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But export to .xls remains actual task

Comment: @GrApDev why? That format was replaced by `xlsx` 13 years ago. Not even Microsoft supports it in Office Online, unless it's a paid subscription. Google Sheets can't read it either. Do you *really really* need to support 17 year old, unsupported editions of Excel? Or is it a mistaken belief that you need `xls` for compatibility reasons?

Comment: Then export to XLSX and use Excel automation to open the file and resave as XLS.

Answer (score 1):

Export to Excel97-2003 (aka BIFF8, aka xls) has been added in January. Check out latest daily build.

```
using (var export = new FastReport.Export.BIFF8.Excel2003Export())
{
    if (export.ShowDialog())
        export.Export(report1, @"result.xls");
}
```